# Sifting through large dataset with Python and storing bits of that data to be analyzed in another script

Tags: python, arrays, storage, analysis

I already have an idea of what I want to do but I'm not sure if it's the best way to go about it. The gist is that I have a large set of data. This data is stored on a cluster as objects with properties I can pull out with ease. I am sifting through this data based on one parameter of the objects, and pulling a few other properties along with it. The script is then supposed to further analyze the data, but that aspect isn't a problem.

My idea for how to store the data I want is to create a class, let's call it 'cutData.' And iterate through all the objects in the original dataset creating a new, simpler object to analyze.

Here is some pseudo code to illustrate what I mean:

```
class cutData(object):
    def _init_(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
#For loop
    #Call parameter for a (requires some shenanigans)
    #Call parameter for b-d (trivial)
    #Assign to object cutData
```

Here are my questions:

1. 'a' in the object class is a time scale difference to be calculated from one parameter of the original data. This parameter is given in the following form when called using another script:

   ```
   Vector([[39552, 39553], [123166, 12476], [203800, 203900]], dtype = int32)
   ```

So for each object in the data this parameter takes multiple values. The other 3 parameters are trivial to isolate. However I do not know the syntax for python that will allow me to create individual objects for each indice for this timescale parameter, each of which should carry b, c, and d which are all the same per object in the cluster data. It is worth noting while I have three indices above, there is no set value for how many there will be.

The ultimate meaning of this is if there are nine timescale indices for a, there needs to be nine objects created each with the same b, c, and d before moving on to the next object on the cluster.

2. My idea as you see above is to create a large set of objects and use methods to call aspects of each of the objects I've created. I am not very familiar with how the script stores the large amount of data though. Is it stored in memory as the script runs and can it be called upon once it's finished collecting. Or do I need to write it to a file in order to call it from a file? This question has more to do with my inexperience, and if what I've wrote is incomprehensible feel free to ask me to elaborate.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I'll be up front by saying I don't quite understand what data you are working with here or any calculations / processing you might or might not need to do before storing it; if this answer doesn't really help let me know and try to be a little more specific :). That being said, I'll do my best to help.

A few general observations I have:

- If you are exporting a subset of a larger dataset, and you only need to move the data, and not any individual methods to manipulate or convert the data (think class methods that do things with the data in the class instance), you might want to store this data as a dictionary. You can then serialize that dictionary out to json, which you can then easily load back in as a dictionary in another script.
  It's as easy as:

  import json
  export_data = {}

  ## Add data with iterations of the larger set that meat your criteria for exporting...

  export_data['data_identifier_here'] = {'key': 'value', 'other_key': 'other_value'}
  with open("exported_data.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(export_data, f)

  ## to load it back:

  with open("exported_data.json", "r") as f:
      exported_data = json.load(f)

If you do this, you either need to do any necessary calculations / processing of the data when it gets added, or just dump everything you want in the dict under that particular thing's key and have the other script do any needed processing.

- If you have multiple values for one thing, it should be a list instead of a string, int, or whatever. This applies whether you stick with the class-based approach or go with a dict.
- If you do decide that you want to stay with class instances for cutData, you can use the pickle module to serialize out an instance. If you have multiple class instances, you can pickle a list of them. I'm pretty sure that when you unpickle the data, you need the same class(es) imported that you had when you saved it.
- As for your question regarding memory: Yes, class instances are stored in memory until there are no more references to them, at which point they are automatically garbage collected. Since you are exporting something into a format that another script can easily work with, you need to write this data out to a file.
- If you really need the class approach and the ability to have methods on each that manipulate / get data, but you don't want to mess with pickling specific instances, you can create a list of instances, and then for each one grab it's **dict** and pack that in a json. That way you get all of the attributes of the original class, but none of the code.
  You can run whatever methods you need to when you extract the data you want to export, and when you have finished getting everything you can save all of the processed data for each instance.

This might look something like:

```
# an example class; you can do the same with your cutData
class fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    # you can define any methods you need to manipulate the data in this class, and then run them

a = fruit("apple", "red")
o = fruit("grape", "purple")
fruits = [a, o] # a list of class instances
data = [] # a list that just holds class data as a dict for each, and not instances
for i in fruits:
    data.append(i.__dict__)
# you can now serialize the data list however you like, keeping the data but not the methods
```

Let me know if this helps or if it's way off the mark.

Comment: This is good information. It actually answers my problem completely. Thank you.